# Magnific Popup causing DIV overlay on page in Chrome & Safari

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, safari, joomla3.0, magnific-popup

I am using Magnific Popup to display photo galleries in Joomla! (part of SIG Pro plugin for K2). Everything works great in every browser except Google Chrome and Apple Safari. Once you click on an image to open the popup and close it, there is an invisible DIV left on the page so that hovering over page content causes a second scrollbar to appear (in this hidden DIV?).

Here is an example of a page with this issue:
http://surfaceartinc.com/designer-glass-and-metals/itemlist/category/417-translucent-fresco-glass.html

Follow the below step to replicate the problem:

1. Open Google Chrome (or Apple Safari)
2. Visit page above (or similar product page on site)
3. Click on a small color swatch image at the bottom of the page
4. Exit out of that image/popup
5. Hover over any small color swatch image at the bottom of that page and observe the shifting of the page as the scrollbar appears

I've viewed a few other demos of this popup script (including SIG Pro demo) which don't have this issue:

- http://demo.joomlaworks.net/simple-image-gallery-pro#sigProId9f0f895fb9
- http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/

It seems this issue is specific to the site I've built. Can anyone see where this conflict might be rooted?

Comment: As a note, I've tested in Firefox, Internet Explorer, Edge, and Opera and the issue does not appear in any of those browsers.

Comment: With a recent Chrome update, this issue has re-appeared and the fix below is no longer working. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue in this case was a cursor setting in the CSS of Magnific Popup. I have modified lines 60-63 of magnific-popup.css as follows:

From:

```
.mfp-zoom-out-cur, .mfp-zoom-out-cur .mfp-image-holder .mfp-close {
  cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
  cursor: zoom-out; }
```

To:

```
.mfp-zoom-out-cur .mfp-image-holder .mfp-close {
  cursor: -moz-zoom-out;
  cursor: -webkit-zoom-out;
  cursor: zoom-out; }

.mfp-zoom-out-cur {
  cursor: -moz-zoom-out; }
```

This removed the zoom out cursor when hovering over the grey overlay when a popup is open in all browsers but Firefox. I have no idea why a cursor was an issue, but the "shifting" effect is no logner a problem.